# how to detect Navigation Buttons Clicks in a service ?Android

Tags: java, android, service, android-homebutton, clicklistener

i have to build an application in which a functionality requires to detect Navigation Buttons Clicks like: Back,Home & Recent App Button and then performing some functionality via Service.

Answer (score 0):

create Receiver in Service Class:

```
 class InnerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY = "reason";
    final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS = "recentapps";
    final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY = "homekey";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)) {
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY);
            if (reason != null) {
                if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY)) {
                    // Home Button click

                } else if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS)) {
                    // RecentApp or Overview Button click
                 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then Register Broadcast Receiver in Service onStartCommand() method:

```
 mReceiver = new InnerReceiver();
    IntentFilter mFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, mFilter);
```

and Unregister Receiver in onDstroy() Method :

```
 unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```